# iscsitarget for linux, mounting on windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, iscsi

I have an issue with iscsitarget, I feel I finally got it working, but when I mount the drives on my various windows machines, they seem to keep theire own folder structure.

example:

one computer1, I delete a file, on the second computer the file is still there, even after refreshing.

on second computer I move a file over to a new folder, but on the first computer, the same folder structure remains.

even the folder structure mounted locally on Linux is out of synch...

in ietd.conf I have this line for my drive:

```
Lun 0 Path=/dev/sdb,Type=fileio
```

My drive is an USB Elements 2 TB drive.

but maybe there are options or cache issues elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your drive officially support multiple client connections via iscsi ?, multiple connections from one client is a whole different ball game to multiple connections from several, if not this wont work and will cause data corruption if you try. You need a storage device that supports clustering.

The only work around I know of is to use the Microsoft iscsi target as this supports clustering, make a VHD file on the storage device then connect all the clients to the iscsi target on the computer connected to the storage, this way only the pc connected to the storage is making the writes directly, everything else is handled as it comes through the target on the 'server' machine. Drives that support clustering are usually very expensive, think £1500-2000 starting price.

Comment: wow, well i am fairly new to this, and just discoered this iSCSI a few days ago. I just decided to use a usb drive to my main machine.

Perhaps iscsi is not the correct technology for me to use when I want multiple machines to the same computer, but more in a native look. if there are alternatives I can use, I would love to know who they could be?

Comment: Hi, if you connect to it using regular file sharing and set it up as a NAS drive opposed to ISCSI, this should do what you need. Usually just turning the iscsi off should do the job as long as there are some shared folders setup on the drive.